# Incorrect Query Building Spring Data JPA Repository For Full Text Search

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to make a full text search using PostGreSQL Database from my spring boot application.

Following is the query I wrote for full text search.

```
public interface ProductSubCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductSubCategory, Long>{

           @Query(name = "SELECT product_category, product_subcategory, "
            + "product_level_category, product, product_attribute "
            + "FROM public.product_category "
            + "INNER JOIN public.product_subcategory "
            + "ON (product_category.id = product_subcategory.product_category_id) "
            + "INNER JOIN public.product_level_category "
            + "ON (product_subcategory.id = product_level_category.product_sub_category_id) "
            + "INNER JOIN public.product "
            + "ON (product_level_category.id = product.product_level_category_id) "
            + "INNER JOIN product_attribute "
            + "ON (product.id = product_attribute.product_id) "
            + "WHERE to_tsvector(product.name) @@ to_tsquery(:query) "
            + "OR to_tsvector(product_attribute.name) @@ to_tsquery(:query) "
            + "OR to_tsvector(product_level_category.name) @@ to_tsquery(:query) "
            + "OR to_tsvector(product_subcategory.name) @@ to_tsquery(:query)", nativeQuery = true)
            public List<ProductSubCategory> findProductSubCategoriesByName(@Param("query") String query);
    }
```

But when run the following query on database GUI tool (pgAdmin). It is fetching me some results. But when I am trying this similar query there are no results.

The console log is showing me incorrect creation of query

```
2017-07-26 11:37:18.439 DEBUG 6332 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select productsub0_.id as id1_12_, productsub0_.name as name2_12_, productsub0_.product_category_id as product_4_12_, productsub0_.sub_category_description as sub_cate3_12_ from public.product_subcategory productsub0_ where productsub0_.name=?
2017-07-26 11:37:18.440 TRACE 6332 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [mid]
```

Comment: I don't think the query in the logs is the corresponding one. That query is generated by Hibernate, however your query is a completely different one. Could you please check the logs again?

Comment: I am getting only these two log. I have rechecked.

Comment: Then you are not calling the right method.

Comment: I think the problem is with this method findProductSubCategoriesByName. It has the property name in it and the JPA is making the name search criteria.

Comment: You can easily rename it if you want but the `@Query` annotation overrides the method name resolution. Which `@Query` annotation are you using?